# google-coral HDMI not working i guess it was blocked by something

Tags: hdmi, google-coral

I m trying to connect google coral with my Tv screen via hdmi, but it didn't work

log :
`[ 3495.356871] [drm] HDMI/DP Cable Plug In [ 3495.364825] i.mx8-hdp 32c00000.hdmi: No EDID function, use default video mode [ 3495.421618] [drm] Pixel clock frequency: 297000 KHz, character clock frequency: 297000, color depth is 8-bit. [ 3495.431699] [drm] Pixel clock frequency (297000 KHz) is supported in this color depth (8-bit). Settings found in row 24 [ 3495.442614] [drm] VCO frequency is 2970000 [ 3495.446900] [drm] VCO frequency (2970000 KHz) is supported. Settings found in row 5 [ 3495.468278] [drm] CDN_API_General_Write_Register_blocking LANES_CONFIG ret = 0`

thanks for helping me.

Comment: Did you try to reflash the board ?

Comment: Yes i tried to refresh it, and i even change the screen, but nothing work :/

Comment: Can you send an email at coral-support@google.com with complete details of the issue? Also share the output of 'dmesg'.